# GPS - FrontEnd II Device

Tags: redhawksdr

I am creating a REDHAWK device for a GPS. I was looking at creating a FrontEnd Interface II (FE II)device for the GPS. I tried to use the REDHAWK 1.10 device wizard, but it only created a tuner device that included GPS. I found the GPS IDL, but I don't see any other information about a GPS FE II device.

Does the Frontend Interface II defined a standalone GPS device?  Is GPS expected to be ancillary function in a FE II device?

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, the Frontend Interfaces II IDL files include support for standalone GPS devices. However GPS support in the wizard is limited to the generation of Tuner devices with GPS input and output as an ancillary capability. The GPS IDL could be used to create a standalone GPS device.  However, you will need to provide an implementation for the generated stub methods